# Redirecting to previous route after login - Couldn't redirect for Product Detail

Tags: spartacus-storefront

After successfully logging in, I need to redirect the user to route that they came from. As I have read `AuthRedirectService` is built for this but when I move into product detail then hit login and do a successful login, it just redirects me into root page instead of product detail page. But it works for other pages in the application. anybody can help me about that ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

The redirect URL in Spartacus is added by the `NotAuthGuard`, that is by default configured on the ReturningCustomerLoginComponent CMS component. Perhaps you have a customised version of the login component and have not configured this guard?

You can follow the default code from the following pointers:
https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/develop/projects/storefrontlib/src/cms-components/user/login-form/login-form.module.ts
https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/develop/projects/core/src/auth/guards/not-auth.guard.ts
https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/develop/projects/core/src/auth/guards/auth-redirect.service.ts#L59

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to protect CMS pages is to configure a guard for any CMS component that appears in this page. For instance, you can protect Product Details Page, by configuring the `AuthGuard` for `ProdcutIntroComponent` (that is likely appearing only in PDP), i.e. in your `app.module`:

```js
import { ConfigModule, AuthGuard } from '@spartacus/core';
/*...*/

  imports: [
    ConfigModule.withConfig({
      cmsComponents: {
        ProductIntroComponent: {
          guards: [AuthGuard]
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
```

There is no need to customize or touch `AuthRedirectService`.

Comment: I don't think you got the point. What we are trying to say is that after user logs in we want to return user to page they came from. e.g. user in product detail clicked login and made successful one so user must be redirected back to product detail. we are having this behaviour at all of the pages except product detail page. what you are saying is "protect your route".

Comment: Now I get it. You are talking about simply being on PDP, manual click on the login page link, filling credentials and then not being navigated back to PDP, but to the home page. I agree you should be redirected to the PDP. With the default Spartacus setup that's a case for me #worksonmymachine. It's hard to guess the cause why it's not working for you without seeing your code. Perhaps some customizations related to routing or custom guards could break the correct flow.  Would you mind providing an example that reproduces the bug i.e. in Stackblitz?